# Insert в checkbox

Tags: php, html, form, checkbox, smarty

Добрый день, господа. Вчера получилось реализовать `Select` в `Checkbox` из БД.
Вопрос состоит в том, как лучше(как можно) реализовать правильную работу `Update` и Insert. Использовать обработчик или есть иной путь? Сейчас если просто запросом делать то он по массиву боксов сажает значения, т.е. неправильно ставишь на 2-й бокс, он ставит галочку на 3-м.

**ПРАВКА**: В ХОДЕ размышлений, было решено отказать от Update. Необходимо выполнить сравнение приходящего массива из БД и массива `Checkbox`-ов. Не получается правильно сделать условие при котором: Если запись совпадает тогда не выполнять действий, если запись из массива `checkbox`-ов не найдена в БД, тогда сделать `INSERT` В БД, и второе условие: Если в массиве `Checkbox`-ов нет опции которая уже есть в БД, тогда необходимо удалить эту запись из БД.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните, в чем заключается проблема, или укажите дополнительную информацию, чтобы понять, в чем именно состоит вопрос. В текущей виде, практически невозможно точно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете. Посетите страницу "[как задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)", чтобы понять как следует оформлять вопросы.

Comment: Не совсем ясна задача, прикрепите пож код и какой Вы хотите результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT :

Выбираем значение checkbox и отправляем его через POST в БД(1 выбран, 0 не выбран)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="type_product" name="type_product"  class="" /><label for="type_product">аукцион</label>
```

UPDATE :

Принимаем значение из БД и в случае необходимости меняем его, после чего отправляем новый POST на UPDATE

```
  <div class="form-group required">
     <label>тип продукта</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
             <?php if($custom_product['type_product']==0){?>
                 <input type="checkbox" id="type_product" name="type_product"  class="" /><label for="type_product">аукцион</label>
             <?php }else{?>
                 <input type="checkbox" id="type_product" name="type_product"  class="" checked/><label for="type_product">аукцион</label>
             <?php }?>
         </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Обрисую запрос в БД на селект
SELECT O.optfilename, O.id, O.descript, RO.optionid, RO.status, RO.roomid FROM  toptions O
                      LEFT JOIN troomsoptions RO on RO.optionid=O.id and RO.status and RO.roomid =
Форма бокса: {foreach from=$option key=id item=val}<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="roomsoptions" value="{$val.id}" "{if $val['status']} checked="checked" {/if}" onclick="chbox()" />
                {/foreach}
Не могу понять, в чем проблема? Скорее всего проблема в том что когда бокс становится активным он становиться вначале

Comment: onclick это для теста другой вещи

Comment: Сложно что-то разобрать в Вашем комменте, у Вас запрос рабочий? Если нет проверьте его в phpMyAdmin, если да, распечатайте и посмотрите что Вам приходит, после выберите нужное Вам значение массива и вставьте его в checkbox.

Comment: Проблема в SELECT, он поднимает боксы со статусом 1 в самое начало потом отрисовывает пустые, а по логике должно быть что они все идут подряд и только статус меняется.

Comment: Что Вам мешает дописать в запрос ORDER BY?

Comment: Получилось поправить?

Comment: Да Order сделал своё дело. Спасибо. Но проблема с update не решилась. Что происходит: приходит массив опций имя картинка это массивом складывается в боксы т.е. картинка-название-бокс
теперь там же происходит селект и он правильно выгружает активность боксов с базы. но стоит допустим взять включить 5 опцию, он передаем почему то в базу значение ни 5-й опции а 10-й.

Comment: Методом проб и ошибок, update норм работает галочки проставляет как надо, а в случае если убираем галочки, т.е. передаем значение 0, то тогда он передает некорректный optionid

Comment: Он магический, когда опции добавляешь по одной подряд все огонь, только по одной, когда начинаешь убирать он начинает убирать с последней и идет вниз к самой первой и по очереди снимает галочки, как такое может быть??? Если в разнобой снимать или добавлять, то происходит анархия.

Comment: {foreach from=$option key=id item=val}<br> <input type="checkbox" name="roomsoptions" value="{$val.id}" "{if $val['status']} checked="checked" {/if}" />
Предполагаю что проблема в roomsoptions, то что там получается массив, а что с ним делать?

Comment: извините за долгий ответ, работка ... чудеса у Вас творятся ))
если не удалось решить UPDATE напишите новый вопрос с описанием запроса и таблиц

Comment: Я думаю, будет лучше не использовать Update и поле статус, сейчас набросаю логику работы на листке для inserta чтобы не плодить кучу пустых опций для каждой комнаты. Он будет проверять есть ли эта опция которую выбрали в базе если нету тогда будет делать insert

Comment: Господа МоСГ сломал, незнаю как сделать следующее: Приходят данные номер roomid, hotelsid,optionid.
Теперь делаю выборку всех опций по комнате:
$q = mysql_query("SELECT optionid FROM troomsoptions WHERE roomid =".$roomsId." AND optionid=".$opt);
после нужно сделать условие что Если присланной опции нет, делай Insert, но в различных вариантах не работает, подскажите где таиться ошибка в логике???
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
  { if($row['optionid'] === NULL)

Comment: { echo "1 Prishlo";
mysql_query("insert into troomsoptions(roomid, optionid, hotelsid) values(".$roomid.",".$opt.",".$hotelsid.")");
   }
else {
    echo "2 Neprishlo";
    
   }}}

Comment: Если я правильно понял то так : if(isset($row['optionid']) && !empty($row['optionid']) { echo "1 Prishlo"; mysql_query("insert into troomsoptions(roomid, optionid, hotelsid) values(".$roomid.",".$opt.",".$hotelsid.")"); } else { echo "2 Neprishlo"; }

Comment: Обрисую, чтобы была понятна больная фантазия.
Поститься массив опций, потом парситься и передается. Дальше приходит Select-ом массив опций определенной комнаты в функцию, также в функцию приходит массив POST опций. Теперь внутри эти 2 массива между собой проверяются и если в SELECT-овом запросе нет опций которая пришла POST-ом, тогда нужно INSERT-ить данную опцию в Базу. Логика такая.

Comment: Закончил на этом не могу понять как правильно условия сделать(((
function insertRoomsOptions($roomsId, $opt, $hotelsid){
 $cn = dbConnect();  
   $q = mysql_query("SELECT optionid FROM troomsoptions WHERE roomid =".$roomsId);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
   if ($opt === $row['optionid'] ) 
   {
echo "TRUE <br>"; echo $opt;
   
  }else {
foreach($row as list($a)) {
     echo "<br>TEST";
     echo $a;
    }
    //mysql_query("insert into troomsoptions(roomid, optionid, hotelsid) values(".$roomsId.",".$opt.",".$hotelsid.")");   
   } } mysql_close($cn); }

Comment: Все получилось, самостоятельно разобрался. Почему не доступно поле ответить самостоятельно?